# Database Query for Getting Max, Min of a column and corresponding values from other columns and Total Record Count from a Single Table in Hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, groupwise-maximum

I have below dataset in a Hive table name - PUBLISH

N.B. There can be duplicate records in PUBLISH

```
DATE    |HOUR|SOURCE|COL_TIMESTAMP              |ID
20200101|14  |A     |2020-01-01 14:18:53.016 GMT|ID_111
20200101|14  |A     |2020-01-01 14:18:53.012 GMT|ID_222
20200101|14  |A     |2020-01-01 14:18:53.016 GMT|ID_111
20200101|14  |A     |2020-01-01 14:18:53.019 GMT|ID_333
20200101|15  |C     |2020-01-01 15:18:53.016 GMT|ID_444
20200102|00  |A     |2020-01-01 15:18:53.016 GMT|ID_444
```

I want to generate below output based on a particular date, hour and source
E.g. For (`DATE=20200101` & `HOUR=14` & `SOURCE=A`), the output should be:

```
DATE    |HOUR|SOURCE|MIN_TIMESTAMP              |START_ID|MAX_TIMESTAMP              |END_ID|RECORD_CNT
20200101|14  |A     |2020-01-01 14:18:53.012 GMT|ID_222  |2020-01-01 14:18:53.019 GMT|ID_333|3
```

N.B. The timestamp has 'GMT' at the end. 
Also I am trying to run the query using spark java code.
Please suggest a hive query which will show good performance, when the data size is huge.

Comment: Sounds like a groupwise-max problem.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a subquery to determine MIN & MAX timestamps for a given hour as as well as the count of distinct rows and then join that back to the main table to get the `id` values for those times:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.DATE, P.HOUR, P.SOURCE,
       P.MIN_TIMESTAMP, p1.ID AS START_ID,
       P.MAX_TIMESTAMP, p2.ID AS END_ID
       P.COUNT
FROM (
    SELECT DATE, HOUR, SOURCE, 
           MIN(COL_TIMESTAMP) AS MIN_TIMESTAMP,
           MAX(COL_TIMESTAMP) AS MAX_TIMESTAMP,
           COUNT(DISTINCT DATE, HOUR, SOURCE, COL_TIMESTAMP, ID) AS COUNT
    FROM PUBLISH
    WHERE DATE = '20200101'
      AND HOUR = 14
      AND SOURCE = 'A'
    GROUP BY DATE, HOUR, SOURCE
) P
JOIN PUBLISH P1 ON P1.DATE = P.DATE AND P1.HOUR = P.HOUR AND P1.SOURCE = P.SOURCE AND P1.COL_TIMESTAMP = P.MIN_TIMESTAMP
JOIN PUBLISH P2 ON P2.DATE = P.DATE AND P2.HOUR = P.HOUR AND P2.SOURCE = P.SOURCE AND P2.COL_TIMESTAMP = P.MAX_TIMESTAMP
```

As long as you have an index on `(DATE, HOUR, SOURCE)` this should perform well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As mentioned, my data has duplicate records, so the query was resulting in duplicates. I added distinct on the outer most query and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic functions to get START_ID and LAST_ID, then aggregate:

```
with PUBLISH as ( --Use your_table instead of this CTE
select stack(6,
'20200101','14','A','2020-01-01 14:18:53.016 GMT','ID_111',
'20200101','14','A','2020-01-01 14:18:53.012 GMT','ID_222',
'20200101','14','A','2020-01-01 14:18:53.016 GMT','ID_111',
'20200101','14','A','2020-01-01 14:18:53.019 GMT','ID_333',
'20200101','15','C','2020-01-01 15:18:53.016 GMT','ID_444',
'20200102','00','A','2020-01-01 15:18:53.016 GMT','ID_444'
) as (DT, HOUR, SOURCE, COL_TIMESTAMP, ID)
)

select DT, HOUR, SOURCE,
       min(COL_TIMESTAMP) as MIN_TIMESTAMP,
       START_ID,
       max(COL_TIMESTAMP) as MAX_TIMESTAMP,
       END_ID,
       sum(case when rn=1 then 1 else 0 end) as RECORD_CNT --unique records have rn=1
 from
     (
      select DT, HOUR, SOURCE, COL_TIMESTAMP, ID,
             first_value(ID) over(partition by DT, HOUR, SOURCE order by COL_TIMESTAMP)      as START_ID, 
             first_value(ID) over(partition by DT, HOUR, SOURCE order by COL_TIMESTAMP desc) as END_ID,
             row_number() over(partition by DT, HOUR, SOURCE, COL_TIMESTAMP, ID)             as rn
        from PUBLISH p
     ) s
 group by DT, HOUR, SOURCE, START_ID, END_ID;
```

Result:

```
dt  hour    source  min_timestamp   start_id    max_timestamp   end_id  record_cnt
20200101    14  A   2020-01-01 14:18:53.012 GMT ID_222  2020-01-01 14:18:53.019 GMT ID_333  3
20200101    15  C   2020-01-01 15:18:53.016 GMT ID_444  2020-01-01 15:18:53.016 GMT ID_444  1
20200102    00  A   2020-01-01 15:18:53.016 GMT ID_444  2020-01-01 15:18:53.016 GMT ID_444  1
```